# "message": "Call to undefined method Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Exceptions\\TokenInvalidException::getStatusCode()

Tags: laravel, exception, http-status-codes

i have done it in two ways. When i directly pass Http status code it works but when i write $exception->getStatusCode(), i am getting error .I don't know whats wrong here.
[image: I get error doing this way]

[image: And it works if i do this way.]

The Second way is working fine but 
what i want is ,it automatically generating the status code rather than being specific .

Comment: have u tried printing only status code using `$exception->getStatusCode()` ?

Comment: btw you will get status code only with HttpException.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that most likely you are using v1.0.* and in this version, the exceptions extend JWTException which extends Exception. These have no implementation of `getStatusCode()` and therefore you cannot use them. 
Tymon states in [this link](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/692) that there is no plan for implementing HTTP specific behavior on the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Status Code will work only with `http exception`. In other types of exception you need to use `getCode()`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
   if ($exception instanceof \HttpException) {
     $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode();
     return response()->json('status_code'=>$statusCode);
   }
 }
```

Comment: when i use getCode() .. i get  "message": "The HTTP status code \"0\" is not valid.", error .

Comment: Yes, because Status codes are issued by a server in response to a client's request made to the server. So you have to use `getStatusCode()` only on `http  exception`.